# Can I generate a 6-Digit random number based on two numbers?

Tags: c#, random

I have two numbers:

1. IMEI Number : 12345678912345
2. Random Pin : 654321

My Random pin changes always.  Based on this combination (IMEI and PIN ) is there any way to generate a 6 digit random number?

I want to do it in C#.

Comment: Do you want a 6 digit random number, or do you want the IMEI+PIN to generate the same number every time (e.g. some sort of hash)?

Comment: yes and i also want 100 unique number based on this IMEI +PIN

Answer (score 1):

How about (IMEI + Pin) % 900000 + 100000?

Comment: i like the mod 900000 plus 100000.  not seen that before!

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way is to seed the random number generator with a function of both numbers

```
Random r = new Random(IMEA+Pin);
int v = r.Next()%900000 + 100000;
```

in this example the function is just the sum but you can find something more senseful for sure.. it's just to give you the idea.

Comment: Compiler error... The best overloaded method match for 'System.Random.Random(int)' has some invalid arguments at line 1 column 12 
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'long' to 'int' at line 1 column 23

Comment: Random r = new Random(IMEA+Pin); 
Random number dosnt accept double it takes int as paramater... as IMEI + PIN is 19 digit number

Comment: Just modulo it to max bound of argument (int)(IMEA+Pin % int.Max)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed version of Jack's answer

```
int seed = unchecked((int)(imie+pin));
Random r = new Random(seed);
int[] result = new int[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    result[i] = r.Next() % 900000 + 100000;
}
```

*edit* fixed answer as per the sudden revelation that you need 100 numbers